# Can this type of URL be blocked by browsers?

Tags: adblock

This is a certain someone's photo who I'm sick of seeing when I open my email (I scrambled the numbers a bit, for privacy. Can a URL like this be blocked?

```
https://plus.google.com/_/focus/photos/private/AIbEiAIAAABECKjd3deErcy73AEiC3ZjYXJkX3Bob3RvKihkOGQ3NTFmZjhlMzAwZWQ3ZjIxhJKlPPoWYVcOZTY0ZWE2NTY0MAFhiSe9L72YBGjaQ7ZC4ltnSxrxSQ?sz=32
```

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: Re: What OS are you on? Windows 7.

Comment: There's no harm in trying. You have the URL, so just add it to your hosts file. Then see if you get a nice red X there. Are you familiar with modifying the hosts file?

Answer (score 1):

If you run an adblock addin to your browser, you should be able to add an explicit entry to the list of blocks that will block just that entry.

In addblock+ for Firefox for example. Go to the options, add a custom filter group and add a filter to that group. Just put in the URL as the filter.

Answer (score 0):

You can put an entry in your hosts file to redirect that URL to 127.0.0.1.  See [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29) for details.

Comment: Hosts file entries don't redirect URLs.  They change the mappings of domain names to IP addresses.  In this case, what you suggest will disable all access (and not only WWW access) to the whole of Google+ from that machine.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about that.  In that case, use the AdBlock Plus Firefox/Chrome addon instead.  That will allow you to block entire URLs.